# Two Submit from normal form and Modal Form

Tags: php, forms, modal-dialog

I have a form to enter some details,in that one select control is there,to select some option(Audit ID) .IF the user could not find the correct option,then he can add in using another button in the same form beside of that select control.By clicking that button one modal-form will appear and the input control is there,entering data and saving it,will save that value in one table (table : auditnumber). And the main form will save all entered data in another table(auditplan).So i have two submit buttons saving different value to different tables and the modal form is just optional..in case user didnt find exact option.

Just i tried these code below..but didnt work. the modal form submit button didnt work.

And i dont know whether this one is good idea. Just im beginner in web app.

```
<?php
include("config.php"); 
include("header.php"); 
session_start();
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM auditnumber";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);                
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();                    
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {  echo $ex->getMessage(); }
?>

<div class="col-md-10 main">

 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="auditplanentry.php" method="POST"> 

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Audit ID:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
     <select id="course" name="course" class="form-control" ><option>Select</option>
     <?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
      <option><?php echo $row['auditnumber']?></option>
      <?php  }
        ?>
      </select>         
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" rel="tooltip" title="Add audit ID,if not present in select option" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#auditidmodal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Year:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3" id="year" name ="year">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">        
      <div class=" col-sm-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id ="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit1" id ="clear" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
      </div>
 </div>     
</form>           
</div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        { 

            if(trim($_POST['auditid'])=='')
                    {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please Enter Audit ID.');</script>";
            exit;
                    }                   
            elseif(trim($_POST['year'])=='')
                    {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please Enter Year.');</script>";
            exit;
                    }

            $audit=trim($_REQUEST['auditid']);
            $year=trim($_REQUEST['year']);          
    $sql = "INSERT INTO auditplan(auditid,year) VALUES " . "(:audit, :year)";

        try {           
              $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);           
              // bind the values
              $stmt->bindValue(":audit", $audit);
              $stmt->bindValue(":year", $year);           
              // execute Query
              $stmt->execute();          
            } 
            catch (Exception $ex)
            {
              $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
              $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
            }       
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['submit1']))
    {               
    echo "<script language='javascript'>document.location.href='Auditplan.php';</script>";
    }           
?>

<div class="modal" id="auditidmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content"> 

    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="auditidform" role="form" action="auditplanentry.php" method="POST">       
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="leave_status">Enter Audit ID:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="audit" class="form-control" name="audit" placeholder="Eg: IA01" ></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" id ="save" >Save</button>
        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="clear" id ="clear">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {           
            if(trim($_POST['audit'])=='')
                    {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please Enter Audit ID.');</script>";
            exit;
                    }                   

            $audit=trim($_REQUEST['audit']);    

    $sql = "INSERT INTO auditnumber(auditid) VALUES " . "(:audit)";

        try {           
              $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);            
              $stmt->bindValue(":audit", $audit);            
              $stmt->execute();           
            } 
            catch (Exception $ex)
            {
              $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
              $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
            }       
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['clear']))
    {               
    echo "<script language='javascript'>document.location.href='Auditplanentry.php';</script>";
    }           
?>
```